# Image Position and croping with css

Tags: css, image

Im trying to make a I Card with CSS, using object position and the like but am running into problems figuring out how to get the text to flow right and how to rotate and the image the result should look like this:
[image: id card]

The horoscope picture being rotated and cropped from a larger master image so I don't need 12 different files just one that's rotated to show the right picture

[image: zodiac]

I've managed to get like 40% ish of the code done but not sure how to fix the position and crop issues

I made a js fiddle to sow my Work in Progress
https://jsfiddle.net/nekollx/43mnzxtq/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="medical">
    <h3>Medical Information</h3>
    <img id="imgspace" src="http://www.toqger.com/images/Lexx Civilian Human.png" 
                             style="float: left; 
                                    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
                                    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
                                    object-fit: cover; object-position: -40px -1%; 
                                    width: 140px; height: 85px;" />
<p>Name: Lexx Alollia</p>
<p>Age: 16</p>
<p>Gender: Female <i class="fa fa-venus" style="font-size:12px;color:red"></i></p>
<p>Blood Type: B+</p>
<p>Doner: Yes</p>
<p>Zodiac (JP): Dragon 
    <img id="imgspace" src="http://www.toqger.com/images/tumblr_ntvd8flyIf1uwilhno1_400.gif" 
                             style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
                                    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
                                    object-fit: cover;
                                    object-position: -45px 30px;
                                    width: 140px; 
                                    height: 80px;
                                    transform:          rotate(270deg);
                                    -ms-transform:      rotate(270deg);
                                    -moz-transform:     rotate(270deg);
                                    -webkit-transform:  rotate(270deg);
                                    -o-transform:       rotate(270deg);
                                    "/>
</p>
<p>Zodiac (EN): Pisces &#9811</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of behaviour do you want the horoscope picture to do? Every click takes a pie being portrait in view clockwise? A little more information about what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: For the zodiac wheel, I would wrap the image in a div with overflow hidden and then just position it with absolute to the right spot. You can rotate by whatever is needed. Think of the wrapper div as a window

Comment: For the card, the layout looks simple enough however where the clipped wheel appears does not seem like a good design because it limits how many characters can appear on the left of it

Comment: for the wheel i just what to crop it as a rectangle and rotate it as needed for the 12 zodiac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a clip path and a rotatation transform.

An initial rotation of 15 deg to straighten the image up and then varying amounts of 15+30 degs per zodiac sign.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(35% 55%, 62% 55%, 62% 100%, 35% 100%);
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.monkey {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.goat {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="monkey" src="http://www.toqger.com/images/tumblr_ntvd8flyIf1uwilhno1_400.gif" alt="">
</div>

<div>
  <img class="goat" src="http://www.toqger.com/images/tumblr_ntvd8flyIf1uwilhno1_400.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: tweaked it a bit but got 90% of the way
cant figure out the polygon notes to make it a triangle showing just the focus (i though i had to make crop boxes)
The only other aspect I shot of is making the header fill the top area

Comment: that was very useful, a bit more tweaking on the H3 to get the top bar color and i'm golden, thanks!